# play-services-measurement-impl: Consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of the SDK

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play, google-play-services

My app got rejected in the google play store, I am getting this message:

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl: Consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of the SDK if available from your SDK provider, or removing the SDK.

My `build.gradle` contains only two entries with a related name space (plus firebase):

```
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"

// might be related:
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.0"
```

I updated them recently but I still get the error.

I am looking for an explanation of the underlying issue and of course how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the issue by removing `firebase-core` which apparently was not actually needed for what I do.